# How do I load YAML seed data for a many-to-many field?

Tags: django, django-models, yaml, many-to-many, seed

I'm using Django 2.2 and Python 3.7.  I have the below model.  Notice the "ManyToMany" addresses field ...

```
class Coop(models.Model):
    objects = CoopManager()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False)
    types = models.ManyToManyField(CoopType)
    addresses = models.ManyToManyField(Address)
    enabled = models.BooleanField(default=True, null=False)
    phone = PhoneNumberField(null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True)
    web_site = models.TextField()
```

In my seed file, I have sturctured the data like below.  The "1" in the "addresses" column, is the primary key of an address that already exists in the database (MySql 8) ...

```
- model: directory.coop
  pk: 1
  fields:
    name: "1871"
    types:
    - ['Coworking Space']
    addresses:
    - [ 1 ]
    enabled: True
    phone:
    email:
    web_site: "http://www.1871.com/"
```

However, when I try and load the seed data, it dies with an "["'[1]' value must be an integer."]: (directory.coop:pk=1) field_value was '[1]'" error.  Below is teh complete trace.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/directory/management/commands/docker_init_db_data.py", line 13, in handle
    call_command('loaddata', 'directory/fixtures/seed_data.yaml')
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 148, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 72, in handle
    self.loaddata(fixture_labels)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 114, in loaddata
    self.load_label(fixture_label)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 172, in load_label
    for obj in objects:
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/pyyaml.py", line 73, in Deserializer
    yield from PythonDeserializer(yaml.load(stream, Loader=SafeLoader), **options)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/python.py", line 125, in Deserializer
    raise base.DeserializationError.WithData(e.original_exc, d['model'], d.get('pk'), e.pk)
django.core.serializers.base.DeserializationError: Problem installing fixture '/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/directory/fixtures/seed_data.yaml': ["'[1]' value must be an integer."]: (directory.coop:pk=1) field_value was '[1]'
```

What's the correct way to structure YAML data for loading many-to-many primary keys?

Comment: Create some in the admin, the `python manage.py dumpdata --format yaml` and you can see...

Comment: Unfortunately that command fails with the error, 'CommandError: Unable to serialize database: Table 'directory_data.django_content_type' doesn't exist'

Comment: Regarding the Table doesn't exist error: did you run python manage.py migrate? Did you remove `django.contrib.contenttypes` from the INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: Hi @ACimander, Running that results in "No migrations to apply." and the "django.contrib.contenttypes" is still a part of the INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: That's not a good sign at all, desynced migrations are never fun, especially if they are intertwined ones. If you are still in development and don't care about your dev data I would suggest dropping the database and start over with all migrations. If that's not possible you can run `python manage.py contenttypes zero --plan` to see which migrations would be unapplied, drop those tables, fake the migration to zero with `--fake` and re-apply them to create the auth, admin and contenttypes tables. But you'll minimum loose all login data.

Comment: If just the contenttypes table is missing: 
```
CREATE TABLE directory_data.django_content_type
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('django_content_type_id_seq'::regclass),
    app_label character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    model character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT django_content_type_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT django_content_type_app_label_model_76bd3d3b_uniq UNIQUE (app_label, model)
)
```

Comment: Thanks.  I don't want to lose sight of my question -- I don't really care about dumpdata, I actually only care about how to structure YAML to allow for inserts of a many-to-many relationship.  I did run your statement, however, and it resulted in a "ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'nextval('django_content_type_id_seq'::regclass), app_label character varying(100' at line 1" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a wrong YAML format for the PKs list, you can use a multiline list as:

```yaml
- model: directory.coop
  pk: 1
  fields:
    name: "1871"
    types:
    - 1
    addresses:
    - 1 
    enabled: True
    phone:
    email:
    web_site: "http://www.1871.com/"
```

If you prefer to use bracket for list:

```yaml
- model: directory.coop
  pk: 1
  fields:
    name: "1871"
    types: [1]
    addresses: [1] 
    enabled: True
    phone:
    email:
    web_site: "http://www.1871.com/"
```

Also, you have to use de `primary key` for the references, unless you define a `natural key` for the models (ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/serialization/#natural-keys)